# c# How to get a value from a method using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

Hi how can I execute all methods in a class and get the value from that call
I'm stuck at ?????

(I'm using .net 4.8)

I would like to exetute all methods when the program starts, to make sure all config values are in the config file
So I dont have ConfigurationManager.AppSettings all over the code but all config values are located in a specific class

```
public static void CheckConfigValues()
{
    var cv = new ConfigValues();
    var cvt = cv.GetType();
    var cvm = cvt.GetMethods();

    foreach (var item in cvm)
    {
        var itemValue = ?????
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemValue))
        {
            throw ...
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class ConfigValues
{
    public static int GetMaxCalendarItems()
    {
          return int.Parse(ReadKeyFromAppConfig("GetMaxCalendarItems"));
    }
    
    public static int GetSomething....()
    {
          return int.Parse(ReadKeyFromAppConfig("Something"));
    }
    
    public static string ReadKeyFromAppConfig(string keyName)
    {
        try
        {
            var keyValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[keyName];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyValue))
            {
                return keyValue;
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.Error($"Unable to read variable {keyName});
                throw new MissingFieldException(keyName);
            }
```

Comment: I would suggest you to write unit tests for the same

Comment: You really don't need reflection, just make your class enumerable and iterate through all values returned.

Comment: @viveknuna I do write unittests but the problem is the values are stored in the web.config file, and I have a copy of that file in my unittest project. But it is a copy it is not the same file, what I would like is to call all med methods at runtime and break the application if anyone for some reason doesnt return a value. Like somone changed a keyname or created a new Get... Method but misspelled the key name in production but created the right key name in the config file in the unittest project.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few suggestions.

You can declare the `ReadKeyFromAppConfig` method as private.

you are returning `int`, and int.Parse gives an exception if the value passed is null. so better you `int.TryParse` and heck for its return value.

I have created a sample class for you, you can use the same concept in your code.

```
MethodInfo[] methodInfos = Type.GetType("MyNamespace.Test")
                .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in methodInfos)
{
    Console.WriteLine(methodInfo.Name);
    var result = methodInfo.Invoke(test, null);
}

internal class Test
{
    public static int Method1()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public static int Method2()
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```